# pass the mongodb bson.Objectid from JavaScript(fronend) to Go(backend)

Tags: javascript, mongodb, go, bson, database

I want to update MongoDB object attribute value by checking object id. that is type is bson.Objectid. I am using `mgo.v2` MongoDB Golang driver.
But in that case I send the `PUT` request to the update API.
I send the `object id` HEX value as string to the Golang API.
But there is error happening in my Golang side when decoding HEX value into `bson.Object` type variable.
How do I do this properly.

---

Frontend :

```
HEXVALUE = "57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24"

var widget = {id: HEXVALUE, position: 2, type: 2, class: "normal"};

     $.ajax({
            url: 'api/widget',
            type: 'PUT',
            contentType: "application/json",
            data: JSON.stringify(widget),
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (e) {
                console.log(e);
            }
     });
```

Go side (Server side):

```
type Widget struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Position int           `json:"position" bson:"position"`
    Type     int           `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Class    string        `json:"class" bson:"class"`
}


func UpdateWidget(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) (error) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var widget models.DashboardWidget
    err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
    if err != nil {
        log.Error("There is error happening decoding widget: %v", err);
        return err;
    }
 reurn nil
};
```

Output

```
log error : There is error happening decoding widget
```

How to decode hex value into `bson.ObjectId` type.

Comment: Can you also log the error? `log.Errorf("There is error happening decoding widget: %v", err);`

Comment: It is ok..but my question is different

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1-Decode hex value into `bson.ObjectId` type using:

```
bson.ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24")
```

2- To update MongoDB object attribute value by checking object id, you may use

```
c.Update(bson.M{"_id": widget.Id}, widget)
```

Here is the working code:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2"
    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    session, err := mgo.Dial("localhost")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    defer session.Close()
    session.SetMode(mgo.Monotonic, true) // Optional. Switch the session to a monotonic behavior.
    c := session.DB("test").C("Widget")
    c.DropCollection()
    err = c.Insert(
        &Widget{bson.NewObjectId(), 1, 2, "c1"},
        &Widget{bson.NewObjectId(), 20, 2, "normal"},
        &Widget{bson.ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24"), 2, 2, "normal"})
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    result := []Widget{}
    err = c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&result)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result)

    s := `{"id":"57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24","position":2,"type":2,"class":"normal"}`
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s))
    var widget Widget
    err = decoder.Decode(&widget)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(widget)

    c.Update(bson.M{"_id": widget.Id}, widget)

    result2 := []Widget{}
    err = c.Find(bson.M{}).All(&result2)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(result2)

    //http.HandleFunc("/", UpdateWidget)
    //http.ListenAndServe(":80", nil)

}
func UpdateWidget(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var widget Widget //models.DashboardWidget
    err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}

type Widget struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Position int           `json:"position" bson:"position"`
    Type     int           `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Class    string        `json:"class" bson:"class"`
}
```

output:

```
[{ObjectIdHex("57f62973c3176903402adb5e") 1 2 c1} {ObjectIdHex("57f62973c3176903402adb5f") 20 2 normal} {ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24") 2 2 normal}]
{ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24") 2 2 normal}
[{ObjectIdHex("57f62973c3176903402adb5e") 1 2 c1} {ObjectIdHex("57f62973c3176903402adb5f") 20 2 normal} {ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24") 2 2 normal}]
```

---

3- Your Code has some typos:

> log error : There is error happening decoding widget

This error belongs to

```
err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
```

Change it to this:

```
err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

to see exact error.

---

Change

```
var widget models.DashboardWidget
```

to

```
var widget Widget
```

Like this:

```
func UpdateWidget(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    var widget Widget //models.DashboardWidget
    err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

---

and

```
JSON.stringify(widget)
```

generates:

```
`{"id":"57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24","position":2,"type":2,"class":"normal"}`
```

This works fine:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "strings"

    "gopkg.in/mgo.v2/bson"
)

func main() {
    s := `{"id":"57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24","position":2,"type":2,"class":"normal"}`
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(s))
    var widget Widget
    err := decoder.Decode(&widget)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(widget)
}

type Widget struct {
    Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    Position int           `json:"position" bson:"position"`
    Type     int           `json:"type" bson:"type"`
    Class    string        `json:"class" bson:"class"`
}
```

output:

```
{ObjectIdHex("57f54ef4d6e0ac55f6c7ff24") 2 2 normal}
```

Comment: @sandunpriyanka : I hope this helps.